# Isset only checks first checkbox from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I have a component that gets all data from the MySQL database.

```
<?php

function component($productName, $productPrice, $productImg, $productID)
{
    $element = "    
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 my-3 my-md-0'>
            <form action='index.php' method='post' id='myform'>
                <div class='card shadow'>
                    <img src='{$productImg}' alt='image1' class='img-fluid card-img-top'>
                    <div class=\"card-body\">
                        <h5 class='card-title'>{$productName}</h5>
                    </div>
                    <p class='card-text'>info goes here lorem ipsum</p>
                    <span class='price'>{$productPrice}</span>
                    <span class='price'>{$productID}</span>
                    <div class='form-check form-switch'>
                        <input class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' name='checkid[]' value='{$productID}'>
                    </div>  
                    <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='{$productID}'>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    
    ";
    echo $element;
}
```

I also have submit button for the form.
`<button type="submit" name="submit" form="myform">show selected</button>`

code to get containers:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center py-5">
        <?php

        $result = $database->getData();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            component($row['product_name'], $row['product_price'], $row['product_image'], $row['id']);
        }

        ?>
    </div>
```

And PHP code to check whether container is checked and return its value (productID) when submit button is clicked.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['checkid'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['checkid'] as $value) {
            echo "value : " . $value . '<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

I have several products in the database, but it only works for first checkbox. Others don't do anything.

Comment: Do you call `component()` multiple times? If yes, then the issue is `id="myForm"` since you can't have multiple elements using the same `id` in HTML. Id's _must_ be unique within the document (it's an identifier for a _specific_ element). And if you have multiple forms, how would the submit button know which form to submit? Can you show the generated HTML and explain how you want it to work? It's a bit unclear since you have one submit button for, what I assume, multiple forms.

Comment: I'm seeing an array-like syntax being used, `checkid[]`, but I'm also seeing that you writing out a new `<form>` tag every time, too.

Comment: There's no such thing as mysqli database. I corrected that in your question

Comment: @M.Eriksson I added code for containers in the post, I guess the problem is really the form id.

Comment: Really, the problem is multiple forms. Wrap the entire `while` loop in a single form.

Comment: Yes, that is an issue. But the question is still how you want this to work with multiple forms and only one submit. You can only submit one form at the time. You should either have a submit button per form, or put everything inside one single form. It depends on if you expect to update all in one go or one at the time.

Comment: I think I'm gonna use onclick="submitForms()", and submitForms function will go through the ids or names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new *form* element each loop.
You can change your function like

```
function component($productName, $productPrice, $productImg, $productID)
{
    $element = "    
                <div class='card shadow'>
                    <img src='{$productImg}' alt='image1' class='img-fluid card-img-top'>
                    <div class=\"card-body\">
                        <h5 class='card-title'>{$productName}</h5>
                    </div>
                    <p class='card-text'>info goes here lorem ipsum</p>
                    <span class='price'>{$productPrice}</span>
                    <span class='price'>{$productID}</span>
                    <div class='form-check form-switch'>
                        <input class='form-check-input' type='checkbox' name='checkid[]' value='{$productID}'>
                    </div>  
                    <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='{$productID}'>

                </div>
    ";
    echo $element;
}
```

and code to get your *components* (function above) and submit button in a *single* form like

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center py-5">
<div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 my-3 my-md-0'>
            <form action='index.php' method='post' id='myform'>
        <?php
        $result = $database->getData();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            component($row['product_name'], $row['product_price'], $row['product_image'], $row['id']);
        }
        ?>
<button type="submit" name="submit" form="myform">show selected</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```